# how to perform a backwards correlation/convolution in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, conv-neural-network

I am trying to perform a backwards correlation (at least that's what I think it's called) on 2 matrices to get a resultant matrix.

Note: backwards convolution works too, because I'm applying this to a CNN.

I have the following two matrices:

`vals`:

```
[[ 2  1 -3 -4 -4]
 [ 2 -3  3  1  2]
 [ 2  5 -6  6 -2]
 [-5  4  1  5  4]
 [ 0  0  1 -3 -4]]
```

`w0`:

```
[[[0,  1, -1],
  [1, -1,  0],
  [0,  0,  0]],

 [[1,  0,  0],
  [0, -1,  1],
  [1,  0,  1]],

 [[ 1, -1,  0],
  [-1,  0, -1],
  [-1,  0,  1]]]
```

I essentially want to apply a sliding window, except in this case all the values of `w0` are multiplied by the scalar value at each point in `vals`, then added with adjacent values.

Assuming a stride of 1 and a padding of same (wrt `vals`), the following code gives the result I want:

```
concat = np.zeros((3,7,7))
for k in range(len(w0)):
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        for j in range(len(vals[i])):
            v = w0[k] * vals[i][j]
            concat[k][i:i+v.shape[0], j:j+v.shape[1]] += v
print(concat)
```

Resulting in:

```
[[[  0.   2.  -1.  -4.  -1.   0.   4.]
  [  2.   1.  -9.   5.  -2.   5.  -2.]
  [  2.  -3.   9. -13.  13. -10.   2.]
  [  2.  -2.  -2.   9.  -4.   1.  -4.]
  [ -5.   9.  -3.   5.  -5.  -5.   4.]
  [  0.   0.   1.  -4.  -1.   4.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  2.   1.  -3.  -4.  -4.   0.   0.]
  [  2.  -5.   4.   5.   3.   0.  -4.]
  [  4.   4.  -2.  -3.  -7.  -5.  -2.]
  [ -3.  -1.   3.  14.  -3.   9.   0.]
  [  2.  10. -12.  11. -16.   7.   2.]
  [ -5.   4.  -4.   8.   9.   6.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   1.  -3.  -3.  -3.  -4.]]

 [[  2.  -1.  -4.  -1.   0.   4.   0.]
  [  0.  -6.   7.   1.   8.   2.   4.]
  [ -2.   5. -11.  19. -12.  -3.  -6.]
  [ -9.   7.   0. -11.   8.  -9.   4.]
  [  3.  -9.  13. -14. -10.   5.  -6.]
  [  5.  -4.  -7.   2.   0.   8.   8.]
  [  0.   0.  -1.   3.   5.  -3.  -4.]]]
```

Which I would then shrink to exclude the padding, so:

```
print(concat[:,1:-1, 1:-1])

>>> [[[  1.  -9.   5.  -2.   5.]
      [ -3.   9. -13.  13. -10.]
      [ -2.  -2.   9.  -4.   1.]
      [  9.  -3.   5.  -5.  -5.]
      [  0.   1.  -4.  -1.   4.]]

     [[ -5.   4.   5.   3.   0.]
      [  4.  -2.  -3.  -7.  -5.]
      [ -1.   3.  14.  -3.   9.]
      [ 10. -12.  11. -16.   7.]
      [  4.  -4.   8.   9.   6.]]

     [[ -6.   7.   1.   8.   2.]
      [  5. -11.  19. -12.  -3.]
      [  7.   0. -11.   8.  -9.]
      [ -9.  13. -14. -10.   5.]
      [ -4.  -7.   2.   0.   8.]]]
```

Either of the two results for `concat` would be fine, but preferably the one that includes the padding.

Does anyone know of a way to do this without using python loops? I'd prefer to use numpy or some other library as it is bound to perform the same calculation faster than my code.

EDIT:

I also want to perform the same kind of backward correlation on `w0`, so using `vals` again but instead using:

`a`:

```
[[[2, 0, 2, 2, 2],
  [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 2, 0]],

 [[1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
  [2, 0, 1, 0, 2],
  [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]],

 [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]]]
```

And in this case taking a 3x3 sliding window along `a` with a padding of 1, and multiply all values in the sliding window by the associated index of the scalar value in `vals`, and finally getting an output the same size as `w0`. The following code achieves this:

```
concat = np.zeros((3,3,3))
for k in range(len(w0)):
    f = np.pad(a[k], 1)
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        for j in range(len(vals[i])):
            v = f[i:i+w0.shape[1], j:j+w0.shape[2]] * vals[i][j]
            concat[k] += v
```

with:

```
print(concat)
>>>[[[  4.  56.   8.]
     [  1. -20.   1.]
     [ 22.  12.  21.]]

    [[  7.  18.  21.]
     [  5. -22.  20.]
     [ 35.  26.  33.]]

    [[ 20.  13.   4.]
     [-25.   2. -26.]
     [ -5.  15.  38.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.signal`'s `convolve` is actually what you want:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve

convolve(vals[None, :, :], w0)[:, 1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[]: 
array([[[  1,  -9,   5,  -2,   5],
        [ -3,   9, -13,  13, -10],
        [ -2,  -2,   9,  -4,   1],
        [  9,  -3,   5,  -5,  -5],
        [  0,   1,  -4,  -1,   4]],

       [[ -5,   4,   5,   3,   0],
        [  4,  -2,  -3,  -7,  -5],
        [ -1,   3,  14,  -3,   9],
        [ 10, -12,  11, -16,   7],
        [  4,  -4,   8,   9,   6]],

       [[ -6,   7,   1,   8,   2],
        [  5, -11,  19, -12,  -3],
        [  7,   0, -11,   8,  -9],
        [ -9,  13, -14, -10,   5],
        [ -4,  -7,   2,   0,   8]]])
```

Comment: Thankyou! I actually was doing some experimenting and found that doing `scipy.signal.correlate` and then doing `np.flip(w0)` was giving me what I needed. Only just remembering now that that is exactly what `signal.convolve` does haha

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html)

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
....    [5, 3, 0, 4],
....    [0, 0, 0, 7],
....    [9, 3, 0, 0]])
>>> k = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
>>> from scipy import ndimage
>>> ndimage.convolve(a, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
array([[11, 10,  7,  4],
       [10,  3, 11, 11],
       [15, 12, 14,  7],
       [12,  3,  7,  0]])
```

Comment: This is a normal convolution. I am looking to do a backward correlation.